# Creating a generic class, with type parameter limited to a certain superclass

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm trying to create a "CRUD manager" class, performing database operations of objects that extend an abstract superclass I created. The abstract class is fairly simple:

```
public abstract class IndexedEntity() {

    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        if(id == null)
        this.id = id;
        else throw new UnsupportedOperationException
        ("The ID cannot be changed once it was set.");
    }

}
```

Now I have a couple of classes that extend this IndexedEntity, and these classes represent my business entities: `Car`, `Customer`, `Lease`

Instead of creating a CRUD manager for each business entity, I figured I'd try creating a common CRUD class that supports their common superclass.

*How do I create a generic class, that takes a type parameter when being constructed, and that type parameter is limited to certain types - those who inherit from IndexedEntity?*

Something like:

```
public interface ICrudManager<IndexedEntity> {

    public void add(IndexedEntity e);

    public IndexedEntity get(long id);

    public void update(IndexedEntity e);

    public void delete(IndexedEntity e);

    public List<IndexedEntity> getAll();

}
```

Is it possible in Java? Or, is there anything wrong about this idea / do think it's an acceptable design choice?

(I might abandon it first thing tomorrow because it may be too difficult to generalize a lot of behavior, but at the moment I'm curious how can it be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

```
public interface ICrudManager<T extends IndexedEntity> {

    public void add(T e);

    public IndexedEntity get(long id);

    public void update(T e);

    public void delete(T e);

    public List<T> getAll();

}
```

and You can create objects like `ICrudManager<Car> carManager = new CrudManagerImpl<Car>();`

Comment: For generic classes and interfaces, you don't need to declare `<T>` after `public`.  Just use `public interface ICrudManager<T extends IndexedEntity> {`.

Comment: Methods declared in an interface are automatically `public`. Variables declared in an interface are automatically `public static final`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public interface MyInterface<T extends MyClass>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the interface line to `public <T> interface ICrudManager <T exdents IndexedEntity>` which will result in an compiler error if you try to insert a class that doesn't match.

If you want your system to be more dynamically you can you an abstract class with an initializer that tests the type during execution.

```
 public abstract <T> class {
      {
         if(!T instanceof IndexedEntity)
            throw new TypeException()
         }
   }
```

Comment: You can't use `instanceof` on a generic type parameter.